# Loop in Rails Index Action is not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code in my Orders view:

```
<div class="grid heading">
  <div class="grid wrap">
    <div class=" unit whole">
      <h1>Orders</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid wrap">
  <div class="unit whole">
    <p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
    <p id="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></p>
  </div>
</div>

<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <h2><%= vendor.name %></h2>
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <h3><%= location.address %></h3>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <div class="grid wrap">
        <div class="unit whole">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= line_item.product_sku %></td>
                <td><%= line_item.product_description %></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :vendor
  has_many :line_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end
```

Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

Vendor model:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

LineItem model:

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I need the following sample output:

```
Vendor A
   Location 1
      Order:
        1. sku:111, description:zzz
        2. sku:222, description:yyy
   Location 2
      Order:
        1. sku:333, description:zzz
        2. sku:444, description:yyy

Vendor B
   Location 1
      Order:
        1. sku:aaa, description:zzz
        2. sku:bbb, description:yyy
   Location 2
      Order:
        1. sku:ccc, description:zzz
        2. sku:ddd, description:yyy
```

and so on.

However, it's showing all orders under all locations and all locations under all vendors.

Comment: You're going to want to go look at the docs for `zip` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-zip). I doubt Relation class responds to `zip` so you'll want to call `to_a` on each of them first.

Comment: I suspect the reason you don't have people tripping over themselves to answer your question  even though it's in an extremely active subject area is that you haven't provided enough information, e.g., you haven't shown your models. Further, the bit of information you have provided _seems_ to contradict itself -- what you say you want (Vendor/Location/Order/Line Items) suggests a perfect hierarchy, but the hints you've given regarding your model describe something different. If you want a useful answer, try showing both your models and a sample of what you expect your view to look like.

Comment: I edited to include your suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should change your associations to have the hierarchy work more smoothly. At the minimum Location should belong_to Vendor and Order belong_to Location, unless there is a situation where this doesn't work for your business case, which complicates things.

You are getting everything in every loop because your instance variables don't account for their parents as you would like them to be represented. Once you fix your associations, you can call the sub-stuff from the object being iterated:

```
<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <h2><%= vendor.name %></h2>
  <% vendor.locations.each do |location| %>
    <h3><%= location.address %></h3>
    <% location.orders.each do |order| %>
      <% order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
        ...
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, there is a simpler and more Railsy way to do it:

```
# index.html.erb
<%= render @vendors %>

# views/vendors/_vendor.html.erb
<h2><%= vendor.name %></h2>
<%= render vendor.locations %>

# views/locations/_location.html.erb
<h3><%= location.address %></h3>
<%= render location.orders %>

# views/order/_order.html.erb
<% order.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When using `render` this way, Rails will automatically iterate over the associations, calling a partial for each one, by default `classname/_classname.html.erb`. Within these partials, Rails automatically assigns a local variable to the object with the same name as the partial, which is why within `_vendor.html.erb` you can use the `vendor` variable to call methods on the object in the current iteration.

You'll probably want to use eager loading on your query to populate `@vendor` to avoid n+1 issues. The upside is that you can get rid of `@orders`, `@locations`, etc.

Comment: Locations don't belong to Vendors. Locations are retail storefronts. Vendors are inventory suppliers.

Comment: They can as far as the database is concerned, and your loops imply that that's what you're trying to do anyway. If Location can have multiple Vendors (and Vendors can supply multiple Locations), then you'll have to make a `has_many :through`. The alternative is to construct a data structure in Ruby that puts things where you want them and adjust the render calls to suit it.

Comment: I'm trying the `has_many :through :orders` way. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It's now properly grouping locations under vendors. However, I'm seeing all orders of a vendor under each location.

Comment: I've edited my <%= typo so it should work as shown now.

Comment: If there are _m_ vendors and _n_ locations, the approach described here will always display _m_ x _n_ sections, even if some of those sections don't contain any orders. That may be adequate for your needs. If you want to display only sections that contain orders, you can use `group` and/or `group_by` which will allow you to construct a list of sections that actually contain data.

Comment: Yep, and in that case it would probably be best to pull from Order so that no empty Vendors or Locations wind up in the query results.

Comment: This answer helped me arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If a Vendor has_many :locations and a Location has_many :orders, then you can construct the loops like this:

```
<% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
  <h2><%= vendor.name %></h2>

  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <h3><%= location.address %></h3>

    <% vendor.orders.where(location_id: location.id).each do |order| %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Order belongs_to location and vendor. Order has_many line_items.

Comment: What the relation between vendors and locations?

Comment: There is no relation between them.